# Analysis - Prove a function that maps the unit Euclidean ball to R with bounded partial derivatives is uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative, uniform-continuity

I am stuck with this problem from my textbook and I cannot see the solution. I'm certain the solution is fairly simple and I am just missing the mark somehow. Any help would be appreciated.

Suppose the function $f: B_1(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has continuous bounded partial derivatives on the unit Euclidean ball $B_1(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B_1(0)$

Edit: Here is my take using Lipschitz and multivariable MVT, can someone please let me know if I am on the right track? Is it as simple as this?

let $x,y \in B_1(0)$ then by MVT we have $|f(x) - f(y)| = \nabla f(c)|x-y| \leq M|x-y|$ for some c on the line segment connecting x and y, thus Lipschitz thus uniformly cts?

Comment: You can prove, for example, that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous (and hence uniformly continuous).

Comment: @Rigel yeah that was my first thought, but how can I show this on the ball using partials?

Comment: Take two points $x,y\in B_1$, connect them with a segment, and consider the restriction of $f$ along this segment.

Comment: @Rigel The definition of Lipschitz we use is that the difference of two outputs of the function is less than or equal to a scalar M times the difference of the inputs. I am missing something to make the connection to solve this problem. I am going to edit my post in a moment, does my method make sense to you?

Comment: @Rigel edited, thank you for your help.

Comment: The restriction above is a function of one variable, $g(t) := f( (1-t)x + t y)$, $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @Rigel I don't seem to understand the path you are laying out for me. The restriction you are talking about, are we using this to show the domain is connected and thus by MVT we can show lipschitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us prove that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, with Lipschitz constant
$M := \sup_{x\in B_1} |\nabla f(x)|$.

Given two points $x,y\in B_1$, let
$$
g(t) := f((1-t)x + ty), \qquad t\in [0,1].
$$
Since $f$ is of class $C^1$, then also $g$ is, and by the chain rule formula
$$
g'(t) = \nabla f((1-t)x + t y) \cdot (y-x).
$$
By the mean value theorem there exists $\tau \in (0,1)$ such that
$g(1) - g(0) = g'(\tau)$, hence
$$
|f(y) - f(x)| = |g(1) - g(0)| = |g'(\tau)| \leq |\nabla f((1-t)x + ty)| \, |x-y|
\leq M |x-y|.
$$
(The first inequality follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.)

Comment: Much cleaner than the way I went about it myself. I ended up using the definition of the directional derivative.